# Implementing asynchronous file system with FUSE on Linux

Tags: linux, fuse

I tried to ask on FUSE's mailing list but I haven't received any response so far... I have a couple of questions. I'm going to implement a low-level FUSE file system and watch over `fuse_chan`'s descriptor with epoll.

1. I have to fake inodes for all
   objects in my file system right? Are
   there any rules about choosing
   inodes for objects in VFS (e.g. do I
   have to use only positive values or
   can I use values in some range)?
2. Can I make fuse_chan's descriptor
   nonblocking? If yes, please tell me
   whether I can assume that
   `fuse_chan_recv()`/`fuse_chan_send()`
   will receive/send a whole request
   structure, or do I have to override them
   with functions handling partial send
   and receive?
3. What about `buffer size`? I see that
   in `fuse_loop()` a new buffer is
   allocated for each call, so I assume
   that the buffer size is not fixed.
   However maybe there is some maximum
   possible buffer size? I can then
   allocate a larger buffer and reduce
   memory allocation operations.

Comment: Wicked. 666... Don't use FUSE, implement a proper filesystem driver in Linux kernel. FUSE sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Inodes are defined as unsigned integers, so in theory, you could use any values.
However, since there could be programs which are not careful, I'd play it safe and only use non-zero, positive integers up to INT_MAX.

(2) Fuse uses a special kernel device. While fuse_chan_recv() do not support partial reads, this may not be required, as kernel should not return partial packets anyway.

(3) Filenames in Linux are max 4096 chars. This puts a limit on a buffer size:

```
$ grep PATH_MAX /usr/include/linux/limits.h
#define PATH_MAX        4096    /* # chars in a path name including nul */
```